# No module named... in Django proyect

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a pretty standart Django project and i can't find a way to import /middleware/utils/compare.py from /middleware/utils/request.py

This is the proyect tree:

```
|--middleware/
|  |--utils/
|  |  |--compare.py
|  |  |--request.py
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--asgi.py
|  |--settings.py
|  |--urls.py
|  |--views.py
|  |--wsgi.py
|--manage.py
```

Where `__init__.py`, `asgi.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`, `wsgi.py` have no major modifications. (`__init__.py` is empty)

```
# middleware/views.py
from .utils.request import requests # This line works fine
```

```
# middleware/utils/request.py
from compare import compare # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compare'
from .compare import compare # Attempted relative import beyond top-level package pylint(relative-beyond-top-level)
# ^^^ This line absolutly breaks my code, but it runs
from utils.compare import compare # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
from .utils.compare import compare # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'middleware.utils.utils'
```

Note: `compare.py` has a function named `compare`, i also tried renaming it but had the same problems.

This might be obvious, but i run the proyect with `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add empty `__init__.py` in `utils` folder.

And read more about it here:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 1):

Change your file tree like this,

```
|--middleware/
|  |--utils/
|  |--|__init__.py # Added this file
|  |  |--compare.py
|  |  |--request.py
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--asgi.py
|  |--settings.py
|  |--urls.py
|  |--views.py
|  |--wsgi.py
|--manage.py
```

And import like this,

```
from utils.compare import compare
```